# Properties of a Connected set in $\mathbb R ^n$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that: If $E$ is an open connected set in $\mathbb R ^n$, let $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be both open and closed with respected to $E$, then  $A=E$.

Intuitively it seems to be true because if $A$ is open and closed, it needs to 'cover' a 'part' of $E$. Since $E$ is connected, then $A=E$. But how to prove it rigorously?

Comment: What is your definition of "connectedness"

Comment: If $A\cap \bar B=B\cap \bar A=\emptyset$, then we say $A$ and $B$ are separated. $E$ is said to be connected if it is not the union of two non-empty separated set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosider $E$ only.

Supposed $A\ne E$, since $A\subseteq E$, $E\backslash A\ne\emptyset$.

Let $W=E\backslash A$. Note that $W$ and $A$ are disjoint. Since $A$ is open, $A=\bar A$. If $W=\bar W$, then $\bar A\cap W=A\cap\bar W=A\cap W=\emptyset$ which separated $E$. But $E$ is connected, so $W\ne\bar W$, i.e. $W$ is not closed.

Then there exists a limit point $x$ of $W$ which $x\notin W$, so $x\in A$. The fact that $x$ is not interior point of $A$ contradicts with the assumption that $A$ is open.

Therefore $A=E$.